# Stop and continue foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I've got a page of HTML blocks and they're all the same. As a result, I'm using a `foreach` loop to duplicate the content (up to 6 times). However, in the middle of the page, I need to break out of the loop, do something else, then continue. It would look like this:

```
BLOCK 1
BLOCK 2
BLOCK 3

(jump out of loop)

BLOCK 4
BLOCK 5
```

I've tried using an `if statement`:

```
if on `BLOCK 3`: 
insert some content afterwards
```

But ideally I'd like to stop it, then start it (as the content being inserted is in no way related).

In theory I could do this with two `foreach` loops (one on each side), but that in my mind, seems unnecessary.

Is there a way to completely jump out of the loop, then return (once some HTML has been written, or a function executed)?

I'm a novice so any help or advice would be great.

Comment: Maybe [`break`](http://php.net/break) is what you're after?

Comment: Is there a way to carry on, once broke?

Comment: `if (block3) call_some_function();`

Comment: `if (conditionMet){$extraContentRequired=true}` inside loop and `if ($extraContentRequired){//echo extra content}` outside loop

Comment: If it's simple numerical indexes, maybe even just use a couple of [for loops](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) instead of using foreach. `for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){//output blocks} //Do other stuff for($i = 4; $i <= 6; $i++){//output more blocks}`

Answer (score 1):

Well do exactly that then:

```
for (;;) {
    if (needsSpecialThreatment) {
        doSmthSpecial;
        continue;
    }
    doUsualStuff;
}
```

(**continue** is a PHP keyword for loops, not pseudocode here)

Comment: Its a permanent loop. As for structure is (before loop; do until; after each loop)

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking this. Something like this should do what you need:

```
<?php
    $temp = 0;
    foreach($blocks_of_HTML as $block_of_HTML){
        $temp += 1
        if($temp = 3){
            doSomethingElse();
        }

        //Code to write HTML Block
    }
?>
```

If all you're needing to do is do something else, just keep track of a counter variable and execute a function to do whatever else you need to do and then allow the loop to continue as expected.